# Can't Generate CSR on Apache2 on Ubuntu Server thru WinSCP

Tags: webserver

```
/etc/apache2/ssl$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout MichaelBauermeister.key -out MichaelBauermeister.csr
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.............................+++
..............+++
writing new private key to 'MichaelBauermeister.key'
MichaelBauermeister.key: Permission denied
140504844809880:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:398:fopen('MichaelBauermeister.key','w')
140504844809880:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
```

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo` ? `openssl` requires root permissions as far I know.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save the KEY and CSR to the folder, `/etc/apache2/ssl`.  As @fugitive mentions, you can use the `sudo` to create the files in that location.  Otherwise, you should try to rerun the `openssl` command while in your users home folder.